# What does the execute bit in the mode argument of shm_open() do?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-memory

I am trying to have two processes communicate via shared memory. I noticed that if I run them with different users, the second one fails on shm_open() with permission denied, even if they are from the same group.
But if I add the execute bit to the mode, the second process does not fail on the call to shm_open().

I would like to understand this behaviour, what exactly is the execute bit doing in the case of shm_open() ? Particularly, can a process execute shellcode in /dev/shm if the execute bit is set during the call to shm_open() ?

The man pages are the best docs I found about this. From what it says in O_CREAT:

> Create the shared memory object if it does not exist.   The user and
> group ownership of the object are taken from the  corresponding
> effective IDs of the calling process, and  the object's permission
> bits are set according to the low- order 9 bits of mode, except that
> those bits set in the process file mode creation mask (see umask(2))
> are cleared for the new object

From my understanding it gets it's permission bits from mode (my umask is set top 0002, but changing to 0 doesn't seem to produce a different outcome).
I keep O_CREAT in both programs because the manual states "Create the shared memory object if it does not exist", so I wanted to reuse the same code for both.

MWE:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    const char* name = "com/page";
    int flags = O_CREAT | O_RDWR;
    int mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP;
    int fd = shm_open(name, flags, mode);
    if (fd < 1) {
        printf("shm_open() failed: %s", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* ... */

    shm_unlink(name);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

As it stands, the above snippet returns -1 with errno set to permission denied if the programs are run with different users, but both in the same group.

If I replace the 12th line above with:

```
int mode = S_IRWXU | S_RWXG
```

Then the call to shm_open() returns 0.

This seems related to when a directory lacks the execute bit, and we can't cd into it. I tried to use a path instead of a file name (with the folder structure in /dev/shm created before hand) but then shm_open() fails with invalid argument.

Comment: What is your umask set to?

Comment: @NateEldredge umask is set to 002, for both processes (running them as systemd services with UMask=0002)

Comment: When looking at the user and group ownership of the file created in `/dev/shm`, is the other user that runs the program indeed part of the group that has r/w permissions on the file? What are the permissions on the file in `/dev/shm`? Btw, according to the documentation, the filename passed to `shm_open` should start with a slash.

Comment: I straight up just get EINVAL. Like @TonvandenHeuvel mentioned, docs say `For portable use, a shared memory object should be identified by a name of the form /somename; that is, a null-terminated string of up to NAME_MAX (i.e.,  255)  characters  consisting of an initial slash, followed by one or more characters, none of which are slashes.` If you intend your code to run on any machine, you should stick to the docs. You could use `"/com.page"` instead.

Comment: @LHLaurini interestingly, I can get away without the preceding slash, in the machines I tested. Your point about portability still stands though.

Comment: @TonvandenHeuvel The user is the one that ran the first program, same as group. (edit: yes, the second user is part of the group, I double checked). Permissions are `-rw-r-----`, which is unexpected, I was expecting `-rw-rw----` because of S_IWGRP in mode.

Comment: @TonvandenHeuvel The reason the permissions were `-rw-r-----` instead of `-rw-rw----` were because I was messing around with umask. Setting it to the original value of 002 made so the permissions were `-rw-rw----`, as expected. It still throws permission denied on the second user.

Comment: @heldertz, ok, I'll try to reproduce it, I wonder what is going on.